# Translate curl command to PHP

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications

I need to know how to convert the code below to `.php` code (which I'm not good with)

the code:

```
curl -X POST -u "<application key>:<master secret>" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{"device_tokens": ["<token>"], "aps": {"alert": "Hello!"}}' \
https://go.xxx.com/api/push/
```

EDIT: I TRIED this:

```
<? 
$msg = "hello from bob";

$token = "72F75474E3360C4C2F26C6AB16FC1E638FE55FCAC92EE4EB4C196123XXXXXXXX";

exec('curl -X POST -u "_rEUqtOtSmSVEBd8uMfdtg:vpB2wmR8Q_2HZ_Jmi37t-Q" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data \'{"aps": {"alert": "'.$msg.'", "sound": "default"}, "device_tokens": ["'.$token.'"]}\' \
    https://go.xxx.com/api/push/
');
?>
```

Comment: PHP has a [curl extension](http://php.net/manual/de/book.curl.php). You can quite easily translate this command directly into PHP. Don't ask us to do your work. Show us what you got so far and we might be able to show you your mistakes.

Comment: As a little help, you can have a look at ready made solution for apns: http://code.google.com/p/apns-php/ instead creating your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [PHP's cURL functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) to accomplish this.  The following should achieve what you want (untested):

```
$handle = curl_init("https://go.xxx.com/api/push/");
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "<application key>:<master secret>");
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"device_tokens": ["<token>"], "aps": {"alert": "Hello!"}}')

$result = curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Via the [cURL library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). You should be able to find sufficient information on this specific problem via the documentation on the different `curl_*` functions in the PHP manual.